# Using C# and XDocument/XElement to parse a Soap Response

Tags: c#, xml, soap, parsing

Here is a sample soap response from my SuperDuperService:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <MyResponse xmlns="http://mycrazyservice.com/SuperDuperService">
            <Result>32347</Result> 
        </MyResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For some reason when I try to grab the Descendant or Element of "Result" I get null.  Does it have something to do with the Namespace?  Can someone provide a solution to retrieve Result from this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
string myNamespace= "http://mycrazyservice.com/SuperDuperService";

var results = from result in yourXml.Descendants(XName.Get("MyResponse", myNamespace))
              select result.Element("Result").value
```

Don't have VS on this laptop so I can't double check my code, but it should point you in the right direction using LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 4):

to extend Justin's answer with tested code with a return that excpects a boolean and that the response and result start with the method name (BTW - a surprise is even thought the XML element does not show the NS it requires it when parsing):

```
    private string ParseXml(string sXml, string sNs, string sMethod, out bool br)
    {
        br = false;
        string sr = "";
        try
        {
            XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(sXml);

            if (xd.Root != null)
            {
                XNamespace xmlns = sNs;
                var results = from result in xd.Descendants(xmlns + sMethod + "Response")
                              let xElement = result.Element(xmlns + sMethod + "Result")
                              where xElement != null
                              select xElement.Value;
                foreach (var item in results)
                    sr = item;
                br = (sr.Equals("true"));
                return sr;
            }
            return "Invalid XML " + Environment.NewLine + sXml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Invalid XML " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + sXml;
        }
    }
```

Comment: XDocument does not contain a definition for 'Parse'

Comment: System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse does indeed exist in
Assembly: System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> list = doc.Document.Descendants("Result");
if (list.Count() > 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: For some reason the list.Count() method from your example above does not exist for me?? Im using VS2010 .net 4.

Answer (score 1):

You're searching in the right direction, it definitely has to do with the namespace.

The code below returns the first element found for the combination of namespace and element name.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\file.xml");
XNamespace ns = @"http://mycrazyservice.com/SuperDuperService";
XElement el = doc.Elements().DescendantsAndSelf().FirstOrDefault( e => e.Name == ns + "Result");
```

Comment: got Error - A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else Error on This solution. How can I solve that

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<Result>(.*)</Result>");
                var v = regex.Match(yourResponse);
                string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```