# How to get a node from xml with c#- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Namespaces and XML are still confusing the hell out of me.

Here is my XML (that comes from a SOAP request)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <MyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <OutputXML xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
            <Result>
               <OutputXML>
                  <Result>
                     <Foo>
                        <Bar />
                     </Foo>
                  </Result>
               </OutputXML>
            </Result>
         </OutputXML>
      </MyResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to extract the actual XML part from the SOAP response (starting with the Foo element):

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://tempuri.org/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd");

var xml = document.DocumentElement
    .SelectSingleNode("Foo", nsmgr)
    .InnerXml;
```

But SelectSingleNode returns null. I've tried some different variations on this but can't get anything working. What am I not understanding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/779976/55209 Check if this answers your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("aaa", "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd");

var xml = document.DocumentElement
    .SelectSingleNode("aaa:Foo", nsmgr)
    .InnerXml;
```

this is because of `Default namespaces` has no perfix.

You can use `GetElementsByTagName` to use namespace uri directly:

```
var xml = document.GetElementsByTagName("Foo", 
             "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd")[0].InnerXml;
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I don't understand why I need the "//" too though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to XML to get your result, also specify the namespace

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd";
var test = document.Descendants(ns + "Foo").FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if you don't want to specify NameSpace then:

```
var test2 = document.Descendants()
                    .Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Foo")
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```