# Selecting Particular Node List in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, namespaces, xmldocument

```
<Report xmlns="Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWarehouse.Report.Alert" xmlns:p1="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; Name="Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWarehouse.Report.Alert" p1:schemaLocation="Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWarehou?Schema=True">
 <Title>Alert Report</Title>
 <Created>6/27/2013 9:32 PM</Created>
 <StartDate>6/1/2013 9:29 PM</StartDate>
 <EndDate>6/27/2013 9:29 PM</EndDate>
 <TimeZone>(UTC)</TimeZone>
 <Severity>Warning, Critical</Severity>
 <Priority>Low, Medium, High</Priority>
<AlertTable>
    <Alerts>
        <Alert>
               <AlertName></AlertName>
               <Priority></Priority>
        </Alert>
    </Alerts>
</AlertTable>
</Report>
```

So I'm trying to pull down the list of nodes that appear under Alerts child. So /Report/AlertTable/Alerts.
I've done very similar before but in this format it is not working for some reason. Can someone point me out in the right direction?

```
  XmlDocument Log = new XmlDocument();
        Log.Load("test.xml");
        XmlNodeList myLog = Log.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Report/AlertTable/Alerts");

        foreach (XmlNode alert in myLog)
        {
            Console.Write("HERE");
            Console.WriteLine(alert.SelectNodes("AlertName").ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(alert.SelectNodes("Priority").ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
```

EDIT:
One of the responses had me try to use a bunch of namespace with p1 but had no such luck.

EDIT:
Did not work either:

```
    var name = new XmlNamespaceManager(log.NameTable);
    name.AddNamespace("Report", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    XmlNodeList xml = log.SelectNodes("//Report:Alerts", name);
```

Comment: Any chance you can use LINQ to XML instead? It's all doable with XmlDocument, but you'll have a better time with LINQ to XML...

Comment: try .SelectNodes("Report/AlertTable/Alerts");

Comment: @JonSkeet - I can't say I've ever used LINQ. I've done a very similar script in C# before like this, but I believe the namespace is what is screwing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this sucker out.
It had to do with the namespace of "Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWarehouse.Report.Alert". Changing this to anything but that won't read the XML properly.

```
        XmlDocument log = new XmlDocument();
        log.Load(@"C:\Users\barranca\Desktop\test.xml");
       // XmlNodeList xml = log.SelectNodes("//ns1:Alerts");

        var name = new XmlNamespaceManager(log.NameTable);
        name.AddNamespace("ns1", "Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWarehouse.Report.Alert");
        XmlNodeList xml = log.SelectNodes("//ns1:Alert", name);



        foreach (XmlNode alert in xml)
        {
            Console.Write("HERE");
            XmlNode test = alert.SelectSingleNode("//ns1:AlertName",name);
            string testing = test.InnerText;
            Console.Write(testing);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From a site:

```
nodename    Selects all nodes with the name "nodename"
/           Selects from the root node
//          Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are
```

So I believe

```
"/AlertTable/Alerts"
```

would work, as that would be 'from the root node' as well as

```
"Report/AlertTable/Alerts"
```

[XPath Site](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Neither work, when I go into the debugger and step through - myLog comes up as Empty "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: And its weird because even // refuses to work. On any node. But I know for a fact that the Log.Load is working according tothe debugger

Comment: Theres a schema
Report xmlns="Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWarehouse.Report.Alert" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWarehouse.Report.Alert" p1:schemaLocation="Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWarehou?Schema=True">

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752735/how-to-get-a-node-from-xml-with-c-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Comment: and change alert.SelectNodes("AlertName") to alert.SelectNodes("/Alert/AlertName")

Comment: name.AddNamespace("p1", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            XmlNodeList myLog = log.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/AlertTable/Alerts", name);

The results from there are picking out single nodes, so I tried to do it but it still isn't getting into the foreach. Its coming out with myLog as empty.

Comment: ("p1:Report/AlertTable/Alerts", name)

Comment: XmlNodeList myLog = log.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("p1:Report/AlertTable/Alerts", name);
Still not budging :X I also tried with a bunch of different combinations of with and without Report, some with / some without. It never breaks into the foreach because myLog is empty.